# What is the most efficient way to increment all values of a dictionary in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, iteration

I have hundreds of dictionaries where all the values of all the dictionaries need to be incremented by 1. What is the most performant way to do that in C#?

I thought of iterating through the keys using foreach, but using the key to find each variable is not efficient.

Using KeyValuePair also doesn't work because KeyValuePair is readonly.

```
        foreach (var kvp in this)
        {
            kvp.Value += 1;
        }
```

iterating through the Values property also doesnt work inside a foreach loop

```
        foreach (var i in this.Values)
        {
            i += 1;
        }
```

This also doesnt work because ICollection is not indexable apparently.

```
        for(int i=0; i< this.Values.Count();i++)
        {
            this.Values[i] += 1;
        }
```

Comment: Are all values added at once, or do different values exist at different times? In the first case, the quickest option is to keep a separate offset integer that gets applied to *all* values, and just Increment that. For the second, another option is to think in terms of some generational counter, and assign the *current* counter value when added - then just change the generational counter in your "increment everything" logic; the difference between current and the one at storage is the number you want, i.e. the number of times everything has been *logically* (but not actually) incremented

Comment: they all are added at once.

Answer (score 3):

> they all are added at once.

In that case the fastest option is: *don't*. Store a *separate* `int` field that is the common count that has been (logically) added to *all* values, and simply *add that* to any per-element count (if any) whenever reading the value:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Whatever, int> _counts = ...
private int _globalCountOffset;

public void IncrementAll(int count = 1)
    => _globalCountOffset += count; // Interlocked if required

public int GetCount(Whatever key)
    => GetInternalElementCount(key) + _globalCountOffset;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that simple iteration trough key-value pairs should be enough:

```
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    dict[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value + 1;
}
```

But if this is really perfromance-critical path you can consider using [`CollectionsMarshal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal?view=net-8.0) class to try to speed up the execution a bit (though it seems to have little effect compared to key-value pairs iteration):

```
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    ref var valueRefOrNullRef = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef(dict, kvp.Key);
    valueRefOrNullRef++; // we don't check for null ref since we are sure key is present
}
```

Sample benchmark (using [`BenchmarkDotNet`](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet)):

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class DictIncrement
{
    private Dictionary<int, int> Dictionary = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)
        .ToDictionary(i => i);

    [Benchmark]
    public void ForeachKeys()
    {
        foreach (var k in Dictionary.Keys)
        {
            Dictionary[k] += 1;
        }
    }
    
    [Benchmark]
    public void ForeachKvp()
    {
        foreach (var kvp in Dictionary)
        {
            Dictionary[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value + 1;
        }
    }
    
    [Benchmark]
    public void ForeachKeysCollectionMarshal()
    {
        foreach (var k in Dictionary.Keys)
        {
            ref var valueRefOrNullRef = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef(Dictionary, k);
            valueRefOrNullRef++;
        }
    }
    
    [Benchmark]
    public void ForeachKvpCollectionsMarshal()
    {
        foreach (var kvp in Dictionary)
        {
            ref var valueRefOrNullRef = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef(Dictionary, kvp.Key);
            valueRefOrNullRef++;
        }
    }
}
```

Gives the following on my machine:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ForeachKeys | 11.405 us | 0.2264 us | 0.2224 us | - |
| ForeachKvp | 7.875 us | 0.0891 us | 0.0744 us | - |
| ForeachKeysCollectionMarshal | 6.971 us | 0.1329 us | 0.1178 us | - |
| ForeachKvpCollectionsMarshal | 7.305 us | 0.1184 us | 0.1454 us | - |

Note that you need to measure performance on your actual  set up (hardware, framework versions) and actual data samples (types, data).

Comment: Implementation of `ForeachKvp` is incorrect. Also, the numbers are a bit misleading due to missing `GC` information. The most relevant cost here will come from touching the `Keys` property since it will allocate a whole list. See source [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6b0c17e49128bc4c5e04a087d45e5201e651719d/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs#L216).

Comment: @l33t thanks for noticing. Will fix `ForeachKvp` now but the rest will require a bit more looking into `BenchmarkDotNet` options since I use the same dictionary the cost should be "one-time" in my case so the test will need improvement for the cases when working with different dictionaries (i.e. allocation will happen multiple times)

Comment: @l33t also it seems that it does not allocate the whole list, just a small wrapper - [see](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs,1491)

Comment: Right. Slightly inaccurate from my side then. But the allocation is there, and unnecessary. When dealing with many, many *temporary* dictionaries on a hot path, it will have an impact though.

Comment: ​@l33t it's not unnecessary, and Guru Stron's benchmark proves it (​`ForeachKeysCollectionMarshal` vs `ForeachKvpCollectionsMarshal`). Enumerating the keys is cheaper than enumerating key-value pairs. The difference would be even more profound if the `TValue` was a large struct instead of an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (.NET 8) the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` collection doesn't provide direct sequential access to the underlying storage of its keys and values, so you can't really avoid the hashing overhead of accessing each entry by key. If you are feeling adventurous, you could use reflection and interact directly with the `private Entry[]? _entries;` field of the collection ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs#L27)). Here is an implementation of an `UpdateAll` extension method for dictionaries:

```
public static void UpdateAll<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source,
    Func<TKey, TValue, TValue> update)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    int count = (int)typeof(Dictionary<TKey, TValue>)
        .GetField("_count", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .GetValue(source);
    object entriesObj = typeof(Dictionary<TKey, TValue>)
        .GetField("_entries", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .GetValue(source);
    Entry<TKey, TValue>[] entries = Unsafe.As<Entry<TKey, TValue>[]>(entriesObj);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        ref Entry<TKey, TValue> entry = ref entries[i];
        if (entry.Next >= -1)
        {
            entry.Value = update(entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
    }
}

private struct Entry<TKey, TValue>
{
    public uint HashCode;
    public int Next;
    public TKey Key;
    public TValue Value;
}
```

Usage example:

```
dict.UpdateAll((key, value) => value + 1);
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qV1Cly).

This approach has obvious disadvantages. First of all it's brittle. There is no guarantee that the current (.NET 8) implementation of the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` will remain unchanged in future .NET versions. Any such change might cause the above `UpdateAll` to malfunction. There is also the cost of using reflection, which for small dictionaries might surpass the cost of hashing the keys. I haven't benchmarked the above implementation.

Relevant GitHub issue: [[API Proposal]: CollectionsMarshal method that enumerates dictionary by reference to avoid unnecessary hash calculation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/58333).